# LInux: How do I diagnose / isolate what's causing "random" hangs and spontaneous reboots?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

So, rather than guessing just what the cause is (though my money's on the nvidia drivers), where do I start looking to pin down some facts?

I've been through /var/log on several occasions but there's a LOT of stuff in there and I can't (yet) spot the important bits.

**Background: The Short Version**

I moved from WinXP to Ubuntu Karmic just after it became available.

Since then I have had a series of *seemingly* random crashes that manifest as either:

- a spontaneous reboot
- a complete lockup with my USB keyboard and mouse becoming unresponsive (right down to he LEDs all turning off).  Also I will typically be unable to ssh to the box when this happens.

I've done plenty of searching and Nvidia seems to be the prime suspect but I have no idea where to start looking to work out just what the real cause is.

Suggestions?

**Background: The Long Version**

At times, I can go an entire week without a crash then have 5 in 2 days.

Motivated by the desire to eliminate possible suspects, I've made a few changes over time to no avail:

- Originally I used KVM for virtualization, I now use VirtualBox OSE
- I had NFS running in the kernel but now use Samba
- I was using Compiz but have since turned that off
- I've rolled from 64-bit Karmic to 32-bit (for other reasons as well)
- I've tried Ubuntu, Kubuntu and Xubuntu.  Same trouble each time.
- I rolled the Nvidia driver from version 185 back  to version 96 (NVIDIA Linux x86 Kernel Module  96.43.13  Thu Jun 25 18:42:21 PDT 2009).  This *seems* to have reduced the frequency of error.

In terms of what's running at the time, this can vary.  The following are common but were not necessarily running for every crash:

- Firefox 3.5
- VirtualBox OSE with 1 or 2 Windows XP VMs
- Skype
- Rhythmbox or Exaile

My hardware is 2 - 3 years old:

- Core 2 Duo 6300
- 4GB RAM
- some breed of Intel motherboard of that vintage
- an Asus dual-head video card with Nvdia GeForce 7300 GS chipset
- 2 x SATA HDDs
- dual monitors (hence I rely on the proprietary nvidia drivers)

I've been keeping current with my system updates.

Hopefully the data above might prompt someone to suggest a specific type of log or config that would be worth investigating.

**Updates**
RAM seems fine
Per suggestion below will re-post on superuser

Comment: It looks like a question for superuser.com.

Comment: reposted to superuser

Answer (score 2):

Linux and other Unix like systems are more sensitive to flaky RAM than windows.  I would run memtest86 and check the RAM

Comment: This should definitely be your first step. Once this is assured, then move on to figuring out driver problems.

Comment: Great tip thanks.  Unfortunately no luck - memTest86+ turned up nothing

Answer (score 2):

Such problems can indeed be caused by faulty hardware (if you suspect the nvidia driver, maybe the graphics card has a hardware error?)

- if you have temperature monitoring enabled (with sensors-applet / lm_sensors), are there any high readings?
- did you do any overclocking?
- did you have weird crashes/hangs/reboots under Windows as well?

If the system hangs, some things to check for:

- are the keyboard LEDs blinking? AFAIK that would indicate a Kernel Panic (ie. Kernel crashed)
- can you reach the system with Ping?
- use the SysRq key combo (must be enabled beforehand) to see if you can get some response from system

  - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key for details
  - you should check that the key is really enabled and working by pressing Alt+SysRq+h on the virtual terminal (switch there with Ctrl+Alt+F1; switch back with Ctrl+Alt+F7)
- after reboot, check log files (/var/log/syslog, /var/log/Xorg.0.log) for last messages

Comment: no overclocking.  Occasional issues with Windows but hard to read much into them - not as frequent was with Linux.  Will look into the temperature monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a hardware problem? I have experience with broken video card that hanged the computer without leaving any traces on kernel log. To isolate the problem try some LiveCD that uses compositing, or better yet: play a 3D game ;-). See: [related post on UL forum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57894/untraceable-stability-problem-of-3-6-8-kernel-on-asus-p53e/61335#61335)